# POST single string Web API

Tags: c#, post, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make an application for Windows which acts like a server for a mobile application (PhoneGap). This application is like a remote for the server application, it invokes methods in which their turn do things.

After long searching and trying to see which components can work together I found OWIN and Web API. So I'm trying to implement this into my application, but I cannot seem to grasp how I can POST a string to invoke methods.

My thought of process is that I POST a string to the server, which it reads and with a switch statement to check the value of the string I know which method to invoke. Very simple, straightforward (not faulty proof probably), but it's a start.

But I cannot seem to get it to work. Here is my controller:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
           switch(value)
           {
               case("buttonOne"):
                   {
                       mainClass.pressButtonOne();
                       break;

                   }
           }
        }
```

I'm using HttpClient to emulate the client on the host pc:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6740");
var content = "buttonOne";

var result = client.PostAsync("api/values", content).Result;
string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
```

But this is getting errors, the string isn't a valid HttpContent. But it's always asking for a pair instead of single.

Comment: You're not passing the content correctly. Try this                                   `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
      {"value" , "buttonOne"}
     })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making POST requests the post content should be of type [HttpContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or one of its derived types.

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
{"value" , "buttonOne"} })
```